# PHP Acces array from different file

Tags: php, arrays, class, include, require

I created an Array in file which contains all HTML colors, (i shorted the list here a  bit)

```
<?php
    $AllColorsArray = array(
        'AliceBlue',
        'AntiqueWhite',
        'Aqua',
        'Aquamarine',   
        'Teal',     
        'Thistle',      
        'Tomato'        
    );
?>
```

And here i call the array and put all the colors inside a select statement

```
<?php 

require_once('../Class/content_part.class.php');
include_once('../Include/Colors_Array_inc.php');


class contentSettings extends content_part
{

public function render(){

    $result = '

        <div class="Content">
            <select>'; 

            $length = count($AllColorsArray);

            for($i = 0; $i < length; $i++){
                $result .= '<option>' . $AllColorsArray[$i] . '</option>';
            }

    $result .= '</select></div>';

    return $result;
}
}
 ?>
```

I have done this before in a different project of mine, It worked there.
The only difference here it's that the second file where i call and use the array is inside a class.

Anybody knows why this is not working? And a way for a solution.

Comment: It's variable scope; your `$AllColorsArray` is declared outside of the function, and so the function cannot access it. You need to pass it in, either as a parameter, or as a global variable. Or, given that you look like you're using a class, you can also define it as a class variable, set it in the constuctor , and use it that way.

Comment: My problem already has been solved. Thank all for trying to help me!

Comment: If one of the answers here solved your problem, then you can accept it; if you figured it out yourself, then you can add your own answer, and accept it when you're able to.

Comment: I can't yet accept a answer, It was solved to soon. need to wait 6 more minutes. BUt ofcourse i sure will mark it as solved.

Comment: Ah, thank you - it'll be one fewer unsolved question on the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed the [`global` statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php):

```
public function render() {
    global $AllColorsArray;
    [...]
}
```

Comment: What exactly is Global and what does it? can you explain or know a link? I am here to learn not to copy paste. Thank you very much

Comment: I've already put the link in the answer. It's called the scope of variables: Basically that's how PHP decides, which variable is available to which part of the code. See @andrewsi's comment above, too.

Comment: Use of `global` in class context is really a bit of a bad programming practice.  What you might consider doing is either injecting the dependency (passing the array to the class) or making the array available via its own class (perhaps an abstract class with abstract method to get the array).

Comment: Ah sorry didn't noticed, new to the site. Thank you ver much. No help is needed anymore. Thanks @Boldewyn

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `$` in `$lenghth`: `for($i = 0; $i < length; $i++){`

Also, `$AllColorsArray` should be created as a property:

```
class contentSettings extends content_part
{

   public $AllColorsArray=array(
    'AliceBlue',
    'AntiqueWhite',
    'Aqua',
    'Aquamarine',   
    'Teal',     
    'Thistle',      
    'Tomato'        
);

public function render(){

    $result = '

        <div class="Content">
            <select>'; 

            $length = count($this->AllColorsArray);

            for($i = 0; $i < length; $i++){
                $result .= '<option>' . $this->AllColorsArray[$i] . '</option>';
            }

    $result .= '</select></div>';

    return $result;
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, i came across that error too. although that was not the solution for the problem i stated. Yet thanks for helping me!

Comment: You mean as in using the array in the same file?

Comment: Yes. As a property. You can access the properties like `$this->property`. You could have a method (function of a class) which sets the array values like `setAllColorsArray( $yourColorsArray )`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, But the array is rediculous long.

Comment: And it's just something i prefer my self, thanks for the advice though @Manolo